# ¿Como puedo pasarc omo parametro un arreglo creado en el metodo main, a otro metodo que lo inicialize con valores aleatorios?

Tags: javascript, array, class, javascript-metodo, programacion-asincrona

Estoy intentado hacer un ejercicio de programacion y nose si lo que me esta pidiendo es incorrecto o yo etiendo mal la consigna, perdidisimo.
consigna;
Crear en el Main dos arreglos. El arreglo A de 50 números reales y el
arreglo B de 20 números reales. Crear la clase ArregloService, en el
paquete servicio, con los siguientes métodos:

1. Método inicializarA recibe un arreglo por parámetro y lo inicializa con
   números aleatorios.
2. Método mostrar recibe un arreglo por parámetro y lo muestra por
   pantalla.
3. Método ordenar recibe un arreglo por parámetro y lo ordena de
   mayor a menor.
4. Método inicializarB copia los primeros 10 números del arreglo A en el
   arreglo B. Luego llenar las últimas 10 posiciones del arreglo B con 0.5.
   En el Main nuevamente: inicializar A, mostrar A, ordenar A, inicializar B,
   mostrar A y B.

Comment: Que tal Mateo, si eres nuevo por acá revisa [ask] y de paso realiza el [tour] para ganar tu primera medalla. Debes proporcionar un ejemplo mínimo de lo que tienes hecho hasta ahora, así podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Hola Matteo, bienvenido, estás seguro que es JavaScript?, parece un ejercicio de Java, por otro lado, pasar un arreglo como parámetro es exactamente igual que pasar cualquier variable.